# Why is Node JS outperforming Nginx serving big static files (videos) on localhost?

Tags: node.js, nginx, video

I've developed an infotainment system for buses where all the Android devices are wirelessly connected to a local Linux (Ubuntu) host. I'm using Nginx to serve the videos and the average size of a video is about 800 Mbs. I just developed a Node app with clusters to serve the same videos, and to check which one, Ngnix or Node, will be a better option. To see the difference, I tested the Nginx servers on localhost and they give me a download speed of 120 MBps, while the download speed of the same files (videos) for Node app on localhost is 450 Mbps. Tests were carried out on the same machine of course. My question is, Nginx is faster than Node, right? Shouldn't it be the other way around? And to the best of my understanding, there's nothing wrong with my Nginx configuration and Ngnix has the rights to CD into the folders. I've tried so many different things with Ngnix but nothing seems to work. This is my Nginx conf file.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##
        aio threads;
        directio 16M;
        output_buffers 2 1M;
    sendfile on;
        sendfile_max_chunk 512k;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

        client_body_buffer_size 10K;
        client_header_buffer_size 1k;
        client_max_body_size 8m;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 4k;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

And this is node app code with clustering, very minimal and basic

```
try {
app.use ("/videos", express.static(videoFolder))
} catch (e) {
    console.log("error in video server:", e.toString())
}
```

And this is my Ngnix default file inside "sites available" folder

```
upstream my-stream {
    server 127.0.0.1:6000;
    server 127.0.0.1:6020;
    server 127.0.0.1:6030; 
    server 127.0.0.1:6040;
    server 127.0.0.1:6050;
    server 127.0.0.1:6060;
    server 127.0.0.1:6070;
    server 127.0.0.1:6080;     
     
}

server {
    listen 12000;
    server_name _;
    #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log mycustomformat;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my-stream;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    }
}

server {
  listen       6000;
  server_name  127.0.0.1;
   
  
  location /videos/ { 
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /audio/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /ebooks/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /test/ {
    return 200 "coming from 6000";
  }
}

server {
  listen       6020;
  server_name  127.0.0.1;
   

  location /videos/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /audio/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /ebooks/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  } 
  location /test/ {
    return 200 "coming from 6020";
  }

}
server {
  listen       6030;
  server_name  127.0.0.1;
   
  location /videos/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /audio/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /ebooks/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /test/ {
    return 200 "coming from 6030";
  }
}

server {
  listen       6040;
  server_name  127.0.0.1;
   
  location /videos/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /audio/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /ebooks/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /test/ {
    return 200 "coming from 6030";
  }
}

server {
  listen       6050;
  server_name  127.0.0.1;
   
  location /videos/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /audio/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /ebooks/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /test/ {
    return 200 "coming from 6030";
  }
}

server {
  listen       6060;
  server_name  127.0.0.1;
   
  location /videos/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /audio/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /ebooks/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /test/ {
    return 200 "coming from 6030";
  }
}


server {
  listen       6070;
  server_name  127.0.0.1;
   
  location /videos/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /audio/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /ebooks/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /test/ {
    return 200 "coming from 6030";
  }
}

server {
  listen       6080;
  server_name  127.0.0.1;
   
  location /videos/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /audio/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /ebooks/ {
    root "/home/khan/Desktop/bus data";
    autoindex off;
  }
  location /test/ {
    return 200 "coming from 6030";
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you been testing these in any particular order?  The test could very well be skewed by disk caching on the part of the OS, if you tested Nginx first, for example.  Might be also worth checking to see if Nginx is even using all your CPU or blocked on I/O or something.  You could also look at packet sizes.

Comment: Also, have you tried with `sendfile` off?  Should be worse performance, but something to try.  Might affect packetization.

Comment: Yes, I tried sendFile to off and it doesn't work either